# Reorder and split the ggplot heatmap based on the clusters in one of the columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I generated a heatmap with ggplot, and order the samples by using hclust, However, I still need more reordering to get all the similar values corespondent with one of the samples in the ordered cluster. Here I generate a samples data to explain better.

```
set.seed(99)
M <- data.frame(names = paste0("g", seq(1,30)), S1 = runif(30, 0 , 8), S2 = runif(30, -4, 5), S3 = runif(30, -5, 5))

M.mat <- M %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames('names') %>% 
  as.matrix()
M.dendro <- as.dendrogram(hclust(d = dist(x = M.mat)))
dendro.plot <- ggdendrogram(data = M.dendro, rotate = TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6))
print(dendro.plot)
str(M.dendro)


dend.order <- order.dendrogram(M.dendro)

df <- melt(M, id.vars = "names")
df$names <- factor(x = df$names,
                    levels = M$names[dend.order], 
                    ordered = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x = names, y = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = muted("steelblue"), mid = "white", high = muted("red3"), 
                       midpoint = 0, space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50", 
                       guide = "colourbar", aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), legend.key.size = unit(0.4, "cm")) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

For the generated heatmap, I need reorder it such that all the dark blue be on the bottom, the middle color and then the red on the top based on samples S3. Thank you [image]